# LIGHT AND GRAVITY TRAPPING IT

Tags: gravity, visible-light, black-holes

Can anything if dense and massive enought, attract light in a way that it can´t come back out (like black holes)?

Answer (score 2):

This is the very definition of a black hole: a region of space(time) that light can't escape, and by extension neither can anything else.

Comment: I know but if a planet were big and dense enought would it too trap light

Comment: Then the planet would be at the point of becoming a black hole. We call it a black hole because it is so large (massive) that nothing can escape.